# How to change prefab in Unity3D editor mode by coding

Tags: unity-game-engine, editor

i am writing a `MenuItem` to apply some modification to a series of prefabs. what i was thinking to do is below:

1. Instantiate the prefabs one by one
2. apply the modification to the instance
3. save the instance to prefab using `PrefabUtility.ReplacePrefab`

a piece of code would like this:

```
GameObject sequenceObject = Instantiate(Resources.Load("Cinematic/"+sequenceName)) as GameObject;
Object targetPrefab = PrefabUtility.GetPrefabParent(sequenceObject);

// do some change to the sequenceObject

PrefabUtility.ReplacePrefab(sequenceObject, targetPrefab, ReplacePrefabOptions.ConnectToPrefab);
```

the problem is that `targetPrefab` is `null`

and the instance of the prefab generate by the code in the Hierarchy is called `xxxxx(Clone)`, which is different with the one when i drag a prefab into Hierarchy, and the latter one can using the method above to modify the prefab.

so anyone can help?

Edit1: my question is the same as this one: [Instantiate Prefab but not linked to the prefab](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/solved-instantiate-prefab.37560/), but the solution is not i want

Comment: Is your Prefab below a Resources folder? Otherwise you have to load it with the AssetDatabase class.

Comment: @JeanLuc yes, it is below Resources folder, and it's clone instance already appears in the hierarchy after i click the `MenuItem` i wrote

Comment: @JeanLuc maybe you can check my edit, my problem is the same as him

Comment: oh you shouldn't use Instantiate, if you want to modify the original prefab.

Comment: @JeanLuc so what i shuold use?

Comment: GameObject sequenceObject = Resources.Load("Cinematic/"+sequenceName) as GameObject;

Comment: @JeanLuc i have tried this, and when i call `PrefabUtility.GetPrefabParent(sequenceObject)` , it also return null as result

Comment: actually you don't need that. you can modify `sequenceObject` directly, because it is the actual prefab, so it will be saved automatically.

Comment: but when i call `sequenceObject.GetComponent<FSequence>();` error said:`NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object`, which means i can't get the component of the actual prefab?

Comment: That means that your path im Resources.Load(...) is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution:

`GameObject sequenceObject = PrefabUtility.InstantiatePrefab(Resources.Load("Cinematic/" + sequenceName)) as GameObject;`

This is what I want.